# MODIS Data MOD09 MOD03

Tags: modis

i have downloaded MODIS Data for fog estimation for the whole month of December 2014 from laads website. 
The files i received are 90 for mod09 and 180 for mod03 for the same period. how do i relate which Geo-location file (mod03) is related to its mod09 file? can anyone tell? i have been trying to run a batch process using MRTSwath tool for which i have to create a parameter file for all the files. i have tried to select Geo-location file but i am  unable to relate which mod03 goes with which mod09.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you have twice as many MOD03 files as you have MOD09 files is that you have both night and day versions of MOD03, while only day-time versions of MOD09.

As for relating the correct MOD03-files to your MOD09 files, you have to look at the timestamp in the filenames. Usually, a MOD03 file is name along these lines: MOD03.TYYYYJJJ.HHMM.005.XXXXXXXXXXXXX.hdf

As such, what you have to make sure matches is the YYYYJJJ.HHMM-part, which is your acquisition date and time. The time-label denoted as a bunch of Xs in my example should be disregarded and potentially deleted, as it only causes confusing for most users.